Are there two equations with no equation strictly between them, but at least one quasi-equation between them?
I asked this question on Math Stack Exchange a while ago, but no one has responded yet. So, I am asking it here. Consider the signature of a single binary operation $+$, and consider the set $Eq$ of all equations in that signature, and also consider the set $Qeq$ of quasi-equations in that signature. I define a strict partial $<$ over $Eq$, such that $E < E'$ precisely when $E'$ implies $E$ but is not implied by $E$. Of course, the same definition can be applied to $Qeq$. Are there two equations $E$ and $E'$, such that $E < E'$ and for no equation $E''$ is it the case that $E < E'' < E'$, but there exists a quasi-equation $Q$ such that $E < Q < E'$? If so, can someone give me an example of such $E$, $E'$ and $Q$? If not, can someone prove it?

The stack.exchange post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977362/are-there-two-equations-with-nothing-strictly-between-them-but-at-least-one-qua

What is a quasi-equation?

@gmvh A quasi-equation is a conditional statement, such that the consequent is a single equation, and the antecedent is the conjunction of finitely many (possibly even 0) equations.
